# Does DotNetOpenAuth support associating multiple Open IDs with the same user?

Tags: openid, dotnetopenauth

When using DotNetOpenAuth, is there support for associating multiple Open IDs with the same user?

If so, where can I find more information on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because DotNetOpenAuth doesn't get into the business of user accounts at all.  DotNetOpenAuth only validates OpenID assertions and you can choose how to bind that to user accounts.

You can see a complete sample that includes binding multiple OpenIDs to one user account in the DotNetOpenAuth project templates ([web forms](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a527c9a4-6032-43ce-9284-d7e3174deb56) or [MVC](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/81153747-70d7-477b-b85a-0374e7edabef)).